# C# How to get specific current time

Tags: c#

```
var myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (myReader.HasRows)
{
    myReader.Read();
    var expiryDate = myReader.GetDateTime("expirationdate");
    if (DateTime.Now > expiryDate)
}
```

This is the code i'm using for getting current time but its getting time of the computer so if someone else try to use this which lives in another time there is a chance him to get fail. how i get UTC+2 time (i live in turkey and i want turkeys current time)

Comment: What datatype is `expirationdate`? if it is a `datetime` or `datetime2` what timezone is `expirationdate` stored in. If it is stored in local time and it is not specified which timezone "local" is, there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: " lives in another time" :) (I think you missing "zone", without it it implies time-travel )

Comment: @ScottChamberlain its datetime

Comment: And what timezone is it stored as in the database?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i'm not sure but i've fixed my problem with this code if (DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(3) > expiryDate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to worry about time zone then use `UtcNow` instead of `Now`.  Of course that means that your database data must be in UTC as well.  Hopefully all of your data was stored based on a single time zone, in which case the conversion is straightforward (just add a constant time to each value).